# Can someone explain this javascript code to me?

Tags: javascript, contains, ancestor

```
var vTableExp = "//a[contains(@href,'newdid')]/ancestor::td/ancestor::tr/ancestor::tbody";
var vTable = dom.find(vTableExp, XPFirst);
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is an [XPATH](http://oreilly.com/catalog/xmlnut/chapter/ch09.html) searching against the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), looking for wrapping `<TBODY>` elements which have a descendant `<a>` whose `href` contains "newdid".

Comment: It could be that the structure of the original HTML of the Travian app you are trying to do this for has changed.

Comment: @Pekka is that directed at the OP?

Comment: yes, as additional info (added it here because yours is the correct answer). His complete issue is here: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1087501

Answer (score 0):

It finds the first `tbody` which is an ancestor of a a `tr` element which is an ancestor of a `td` element which is an ancestor of an `a` element whose `href` contains the string `newdid`. (IOW, assuming that the parsed document is (X)HTML, select the body of the first table that has a cell containing a link whose address contains the string `newdid`.)

Answer (score -3):

`vTableExp` is probably a regexp pattern and then it's being searched for.

Comment: It looks more like an XPath than a regular expression …